# Python - Printing/Reading first Element generally any element of bytes object

Tags: python, byte

How can I print/reading the first element or generally any elements of bytes object?

```
a = b'BMv\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I know that the first element is `b'B'`. I can read it with `a[0]` but it returns me the INT value 66. I know this stands for the `b'B'` because I get from `int.from_bytes(b'B', byteorder='big')` the value 66. What can I do to get `b'B'` instead of the INT value 66?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, slices are instances of parent types. `a[:1]` is a `bytes` object of length 1:

```
In [6]: a[:1]
Out[6]: b'B'
```

You can also convert a list of integers (all integers must be in **[** *0*, *255* **]**) to `bytes` object by passing that list to the `bytes` constructor:

```
In [7]: bytes([a[0]])
Out[7]: b'B'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. Tried to convert it but totally forgot the outer brackets from `a[0]`.